# Prevent status bar from auto-hide in full screen activity

Tags: android, overlay, android-fullscreen, android-statusbar

I want status bar to be transparent and overlay on my activity while navigation bar is displayed normally.

[e.g. Status bar overlay in Google app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCTEA.png)

I have set the activity to be full screen by using code:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

The above code does hide the status bar and it does not make any changes to navigation bar.
Now i need to know how to set status bar to become overlay on activity

The status bar does overlay when swiping down from top edge of screen but it auto hides. I want it to remain on the screen.
Can someone tell how do i make it happen? I know it is possible because Google app is using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set custom themes to different activity layouts. Just add a new style to your styles.xml :

```
<style name="MY.ACTIVITY" parent="android:Theme" >
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">false</item>
</style>
```

add this style to the activity in AndroidManifest.xml ,

and in the `onCreate()` of your activity:

```
int width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
int height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
```

Comment: This did not work, the status bar still auto hides. I tested on Android 6.0 emulator

Comment: It crashes with android:theme, error says to use Theme.AppCompat. The Action bar also shows with it. I don't need any action bar. i have a scrolling feed similar to Google App. The Action bar should stay as overlay on the screen

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
  getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
```